# S3 Location is not allowed by storage integration when creating a stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a storage integration in Snowflake that allows access to `s3://bucket-name/` however when I try to create a stage using that storage integration and provide the `s3://bucket-name/` value to the URL parameter, I receive a message like this:

```
Location 's3://bucket-name/' is not allowed by integration STORAGE_INTEGRATION_BUCKET_NAME. Please use DESC INTEGRATION to check out allowed and blocked locations.
```

Running DESC INTEGRATION on the integration clearly shows me that `s3://bucket-name/` is within the allowed locations.

Is there some sort of gotcha when trying to enable a stage on the base path of an S3 URL? The end goal is creating a Snowpipe that uses this stage.

Comment: I should clarify that allowing a location like 's3://bucket-name/a/b/c' and specifying that location in the stage creates the stage with no issues.

Comment: Have same issue. Same `CREATE STAGE` works in UI but raises error in Python

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by providing the path without the trailing slash. As in like this:

> s3://bucket-name

while trying to create the stage and see if it works.

The logic for path in stage is derived from Allowed locations which it sees if it has trailing slash or not .

For eg:

Case 1 : ALLOWED_STORAGE_LOCATION=s3://abcd/path/

Stage URL may be:

> s3://abcd/path/

> s3://abcd/path/sub/

Case 2 : ALLOWED_STORAGE_LOCATION=s3://abcd/path

Stage URL can be:

> s3://abcd/path/
>
> s3://abcd/path
>
> s3://abcd/path2
>
> s3://abcd/path3
>
> s3://path/sub/

The ALLOWED_STORAGE_LOCATION specifies the prefix that the stage URL must begin with. If you'd like this to end in a directory, you would use a trailing slash, but if it is a prefix that may contain variations after the match, then you would want to remove the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue - what solved it for me was ensuring SQL query had the correct case i.e. CAPS for keywords and lowercase for things like s3 uri.
e.g.

```sql
        COPY INTO MY_DATABASE.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
        FROM 's3://s3_bucket/s3_folder/'
        STORAGE_INTEGRATION = MY_STORAGE_INTEGRATION
        FILE_FORMAT = (
            TYPE = CSV
            SKIP_HEADER = 1
            SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE
            FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
        )
```

My Python code was upper casing the S3 location - once I fixed that it worked.

Use print or logging messages to show what SQL Python is actually executing.